# Border top left and right radius not working on my div element

Tags: css

I want curves at the top left and top right corners of my `div`. I tried `border-top-left-radius` and `border-top-right-radius` but it doesn't seem to be working.

HTML:

```
 <div id="trape"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#trape{
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 0 solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
}
```

I want output something like shown in the below image

[image: desired output]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `border-top-left-radius` and `border-top-right-radius` css like this :

```
#trape{
background-color: #E0E0E0;
border-left: 0 solid transparent;
border-top-left-radius: 2em;
border-top-right-radius: 10em;
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
color: white;
width: 200px;
}
```

```css
#trape{
background-color: #E0E0E0;
border-left: 0 solid transparent;
border-top-left-radius: 2em;
border-top-right-radius: 10em;
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
color: white;
width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="trape">Abstract Murals</div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: can we still more straighten in the top right? looks too much curve! Something like i shown in the reference image :)

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem..

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    Your content goes here
  </div>
</div>
```